# Launch rest of launch file after one process exits

Tags: ros2, launch

I have a ros2 launch file script that instantiates nodes and also calls other launch files. I want to add the launch of another process and only instantiate the other nodes and launch files when this process exits. The reason is that this process essentially reads a configuration file and defines environment variables that the rest of the launch file script needs.

Is this possible and if so, how? I know you can register an event handler on process exit and start a node using this? Is this the only way i.e. I have to add this event handler to every node? Does this work with launching other launch files which uses the ExecuteProcess action?